# Solr PatternTokenizerFactory does not work with phrases

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solr6

I can't get PatternTokenizerFactory to match multiple words at a time.  If I use a simple expression such as "^keyword$" and search for "keyword", it will work

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="^keyword$" group="0" />

"querystring":"keyword",    
"parsedquery":"(+DisjunctionMaxQuery(((title:keyword)^2.0)))/no_coord",
```

However the moment I include a space in the expression, it breaks.  ie 
 my expression is "^key.word$" and I search for "key word" it will not work

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="^key.word$" group="0" />    

"querystring":"key word",
"parsedquery":"(+())/no_coord",
```

I can't figure out why this is not working.  I am trying to match phrases built up from some clever regex, but can't figure out what's going on.

I've checked the regex in multiple testers and it works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Solr 6.1

Comment: How are you querying? If you're using the edismax handler, it has [a parameter that defaults to true for split on whitespace](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-ThesowParameter) (`sow=false` would disable it) before analysis.

Comment: I am using edismax. I will try this and get back to you. Please add as an answer so I can mark as solution if correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using edismax, the `sow` (split on whitespace) parameter is true by default. This makes edismax split the content *before* running it through analysis.

> The `sow` Parameter
>
> Split on whitespace: if set to false, whitespace-separated term sequences will be provided to text analysis in one shot, enabling proper function of analysis filters that operate over term sequences, e.g. multi-word synonyms and shingles. Defaults to true: text analysis is invoked separately for each individual whitespace-separated term.